# PCL removing outliers using radius as condition

Tags: ros, filter, pcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi I'm using a radius filter to remove outliers from my pointcloud, however the code hangs while creating the filtering object. The code never gotten to the point of outputting the message "cloud after filtering".

```
std::cerr << "Cloud before statistical filtering: " << std::endl;
std::cerr << *PCL1_temp_cloud << std::endl;
// Create the filtering object
pcl::RadiusOutlierRemovalpcl::PointXYZ outrem;
outrem.setInputCloud(PCL1_temp_cloud);
outrem.setRadiusSearch(0.8);
outrem.setMinNeighborsInRadius (2);
outrem.filter (*PCL1_cloud_filtered);
std::cerr << "Cloud after filtering: " << std::endl;   // code stops before this point
std::cerr << *PCL1_cloud_filtered << std::endl;
pcl::toROSMsg    (*PCL1_cloud_filtered, output);
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/226304/pcl-removing-outliers-using-radius-as-condition/) by [jhlim6](https://answers.ros.org/users/25845/jhlim6/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2016-02-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is this line intended?

```
 sor.filter (PCL1_cloud_filtered);
```

It is possibly for statistical outlier removal. If it is not related, you can try removing it.

---

Originally posted by [Akif](https://answers.ros.org/users/23527/akif/) with karma: 3561 on 2016-02-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jhlim6](https://answers.ros.org/users/25845/jhlim6/) on 2016-02-11**:
Mistake when pasting the code. Statistical outlier removal works for me. But it doesn't fully remove all the noise.

**Comment by [Akif](https://answers.ros.org/users/23527/akif/) on 2016-02-11**:
Did you try debugging with something like gdb? Do you have any console output?

**Comment by [jhlim6](https://answers.ros.org/users/25845/jhlim6/) on 2016-02-11**:
I used rviz to note that the pointcloud was present prior to filtering. It output the cloud details before filtering, but after that it hangs.